# Change port in UDP Socket C#

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I'm working on a UDP Server-Client application.

When I create a new client, the client connect to the server and they begin to exchange data

This is my client constructor:

```
static EndPoint serverEP;
static Socket clientSocket;
public Client(Player client)
{        
    clientSocket = clientSocket = new Socket(
            AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Dgram,
            ProtocolType.Udp);

    clientSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,0));
    clientSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

    serverEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Server.serverIp), port);
}
```

After few actions I want to connect to another server.

My question is, is it possible to change port in the socket client?

I have tried this but it does not work, the program stay stuck:

```
public void changePort(int newPort)
{
    clientSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));
    serverEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Server.serverIp), newPort);
}
```

It is a solution to close a socket like this:

```
public void CloseSocket()
{        
    clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
    clientSocket.Close();        
}
```

and start a new client on the new Port ?

Comment: `clientSocket = clientSocket = new Socket(`  ... that ... is ... unexpected.

Comment: why not use the connect variant ,that allows you to put a specific port?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4w4cta7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What do you ask when you already typed "it is a solution..." (or is that what's been edited)?

Comment: Because I don't know if it is a good solution...